# Last free of multidimensional array wont work

Tags: c, malloc, free

I've written the following function:

```
/*!
 * @brief Loads the filecontent from the whitelist into an array of structs
 * @param char *conffile - The whitelist file
 * @param struct whitelist *confstruct - The array of structs
 * @param int conflines - How many lines are in the given file
 * @return int - 0 on succes, 1 on error
 */

int load_whitelist(char *conffile, struct s_whitelist *confstruct, int conflines)
{
    FILE *infile;

    if((infile = fopen(conffile, "r")) == NULL)                             // Try to open given file
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "File error!");                                     // Error on failure        
            return 1;                           
        }

    char line[256];
    char *buffer;
    char **linebuffer;

    int i = 0;

    while(i <= conflines)                                                   // As long as there are lines in the file (except comments starting with #) 
        {
            confstruct[i].name = malloc(256);                                   // Allocate memory for the regarding part of the struct
            confstruct[i].gateway = malloc(256);
            confstruct[i].user = malloc(256);
            confstruct[i].pass = malloc(256);
            confstruct[i].cert = malloc(256);

            while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), infile) != NULL)                    // Get lines until the end of the file is reached
                {
                    if(line[0] != '#')                                              // If a line doesn't contain a '#'
                        {
                            linebuffer = malloc(count_string(line," ")+1);              // Allocate memory in the linebuffer for every found blank
                            for(int y = 0; y <= count_string(line," "); y++)            // For every found blank
                                {
                                    linebuffer[y] = malloc(256);                            // allocate memory in the array
                                }

                            printf("%i| %s\n",count_string(line," "),line);
                        }
                }
            i++;
        }

    for(int y = 0; y <= count_string(line," "); y++)
        {
            free(linebuffer[y]);
        }
    free(linebuffer);  // <---- That's the culprint
    return 0;
}
```

Everthing works, except the last free(linebuffer). I've tried different positions, different kinds of pointer, even if I just have found this way in the examples. So, anyone got an idea what I did wrong this time? 
Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You realize you never actually use `linebuffer`, right?

Comment: What do you mean by *"wont' work"* - describe the actual problem

Comment: You're allocating `linebuffer` every time through the `while fgets` loop, but only freeing it once. That's a huge memory leak.

Comment: The nested loops don't seem right. The outer loop runs for every line in the file, and so does the inner loop. The inner loop will read the entire file the first time through the outer loop. When the outer loop repeats, the inner loop will stop immediately because it will be at EOF.

Comment: There is no multidimensional array! `char **` is a pointer to pointer, not an array of arrays. Completely different types.